# Yii 2 application deployment in laragon local server with virtual hosts

Tags: virtualhost, yii2-advanced-app, laragon

How to deploy yii 2 application on laragon local server ? 
Laragon automatically creates virtual host file but after changing that server breaks. Application is in C:/laragon/www/yii-app folder laragons created auto.yii-app.conf virtual host file

```
define ROOT "C:/laragon/www/yii-app"
define SITE "yii-app"

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "${ROOT}"
    ServerName ${SITE}
    ServerAlias *.${ALIAS}
    <Directory "${ROOT}">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm changing that to this

```
define ROOT "C:/laragon/www/yii-app/frontend/web"
define SITE "front.yii.com"

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "${ROOT}"
    ServerName ${SITE}
    ServerAlias *.${ALIAS}
    <Directory "${ROOT}">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

after server breaks and application didn't work. 
Also I'm removing the "auto." prefix from the Virtual Host file from "auto.yii-app.conf" to "yii-app.conf" because every time when apache is reloading laragon rewrites all virtual host files which have "auto" prefix.

What I'm doing wrong? And how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You did not define **ALIAS**. Just replace it with **SITE**:

```
define ROOT "C:/laragon/www/yii-app/frontend/web"
define SITE "front.yii.com"

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "${ROOT}"
    ServerName ${SITE}
    ServerAlias *.${SITE}
    <Directory "${ROOT}">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Btw - when having errors, the first action you should take is checking Apache error.log (**Menu > Apache > error.log**)